# Facebook Open Graph - How to add new property?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I wanna build a **facebook application** and I have set up new story using open graph (i.e. "*likes an article*").

So my object is the `article` while the action is `likes`...

Now I want to add a new property to my action which I can display in the status message later on. See picture below:

[image]

When clicking the Save-Button it seems to be saved but when reloading the page there are no properties added.

**First question:** How to add properties correctly?

**Second question:** How to insert my action property into my status message via Open Graph (see picture below)?

[image]

*EDIT: I have analyzed the AJAX call via firebug in my browser when I click on the Save-Button: I always get a 500 errorcode. So in my opinion it's only a bug in the open graph interface, but how do I add properties without interface?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/304977889645548) on facebook (Open Graph) has been fixed, so now I can add properties to an action again ;)

To my second question: If you add property `my_property` to your action you only have to insert `{my_property}` into your status message via Open Graph...